# ADFS Client Certificate Authentication

Tags: windows, adfs, single-sign-on, x509, saml

I have ADFS on my environment and it's currently authenticating via active directory perfectly fine. I'm trying to enable certificate authentication so they can authenticate with their smart cards. Currently, the smart cards are imported into their AD accounts and they can successfully get prompted to select the correct certificate and login (just not from ADFS). I also checked that the clients Root CA's are all located within the Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate store and they're all present.

Within ADFS, I have certificate authentication enabled, inbound port 49443 (inbound from client to ADFS server), and the certificate login selection is showing on the ADFS login page. When I hit certificate login I receive the following error:

" An error occurred. No valid client certificate found in the request. No valid certificates found in the user's certificate store. Please try again after closing and reopening the browser and choose a different authentication method.

Activity ID: 25ef4526-fcb4-4f64-0c00

Error details: MSIS7121: The request did not contain a valid client certificate that can be used for authentication. This occurs when there are no valid certificates on the client computer, for example if all certificates have expired or been revoked. Error Code: 0x490

Node name: a22ee49a-fa2d

Error time: Tue, 20 Dec 2022 14:55:31 GMT

Cookie: enabled

User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

I get this whether I'm on a client computer and directly on the ADFS server itself in a web browser. Has anyone every encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case where you need to map the certificate to the user.  Try this on your AD server:

To map the x509 certificate to an individual user go to: dsa.msc (AD Users and Computers) -> Enable Advanced Features -> right-click on user -> Name Mappings.

There you can map the certificate to the user who is trying to authenticate using cert auth.

Hope that helps.